# Google Analytics causes error on Cordova app only after I sign my APK

Tags: android, cordova, google-analytics, cordova-plugins

I am using [google-analytics-plugin](https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin) for my Ionic/Cordova application. Everything works fine when I am in debugging mode, with this code:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    if (typeof analytics !== "undefined") {
        analytics.startTrackerWithId("UA-x-x");
    } else {
        console.log("Google Analytics Unavailable");
    }
});
```

And whichever template(page) needs tracking, I add this to it's controller:

```
analytics.trackView('my-page');
```

But after I sign my application with my keystore file and then install the apk, the app is stuck on the `index.html` page, i.e. the error is with any template that has analytics running. I checked the logcat and I found this:

```
D/CordovaLog(29315): file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js: Line 19387 : ReferenceError: analytics is not defined
D/CordovaLog(29315):     at new <anonymous> (file:///android_asset/www/js/controllers.js:224:5)
D/CordovaLog(29315):     at invoke (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11994:17)
D/CordovaLog(29315):     at Object.instantiate (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:12002:27)
D/CordovaLog(29315):     at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:16255:28
D/CordovaLog(29315):     at self.appendViewElement (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:47320:24)
D/CordovaLog(29315):     at Object.switcher.render (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:45864:41)
D/CordovaLog(29315):     at Object.switcher.init (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:45784:20)
D/CordovaLog(29315):     at self.render (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:47225:14)
D/CordovaLog(29315):     at self.register (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:47181:10)
D/CordovaLog(29315):     at updateView (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:50834:23)
```

Comment: Error is "analytics is not defined". Can you check in your plugins folder in platforms/android is this google-analytics is available? From some reason your plugin is not visible to your app.

Comment: Yes it is available. And, incase if you missed it, the plugin does work when the apk isn't signed.

Comment: Yes it is strange. Is there any error before this one in logs. This error means that plugin is not "visible". Because plugin is there as you said, it must be some error in loading cordova context, maybe or before this one that cause plugin is not available. Is there anything in web browser console when you reload page?

Comment: On a web browser it says "Google Analytics Unavailable", which is fine cause it won't work on the browser. And no, there aren't any errors related to Cordova(I'm filtering them with `adb logcat CordovaLog:D *:S`). If you know that this isn't right way to read the logs, do let me know.

Comment: When I am saying to debug in browser, I am thinking to run app on device but to debug on browser. Please check this link https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging.

Comment: If I am getting it right, you mean I have to test the application on my phone's Chrome browser and view the console logs on my computer? If yes, then even Android's chrome browser won't run any cordova's plugins.

Comment: No. If you have Android version 4.4 and later, you can run you application on real device or emulator, and debug your web view in Chrome on your desktop.

Comment: Oh, so I will have to try a plugin when I get my hands on a device having 4.4+, or might try on an emulator tomorrow morning.

Comment: Try on emulator with version 4.4+. Then you can see if there is some additional errors, and what is more important you can debug js code close to error line.

Comment: Sorry for reverting back late. And it's the same error that I got on logcat. `ReferenceError: analytics is not defined
    at new <anonymous> (file:///android_asset/www/js/controllers.js:225:5) .....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the problem was occurring under weird circumstances, the solution had to be more weird. I got rid of the double quotes around **undefined** in my `$ionicPlatform.ready` function and it worked. So now the code looks like:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    if (typeof analytics !== undefined) {
        analytics.startTrackerWithId("UA-x-x");
    } else {
        console.log("Google Analytics Unavailable");
    }
});
```

Credits go to [Nic Raboy](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/06/using-google-analytics-ionicframework/#comment-1925242389) for mentioning this possibility.